# How to quelch or debug "Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

The following error is filling up our log files to the point of making them unreadable:

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression
*/var/www/cnn.com.com/gift-shop/var/log/exception.log*: [2017-08-04 1:31:19]  
main.ERROR: Exception: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in  
/var/www/cnn.com/gift-shop/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on  
line 269 in .../vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
```

If I mute this I get a warning on the upcoming foreach after that line.
I assume muting that would continue this chain.
What can I do to begin debugging this?

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar issue and found the cause for my case.

This issue might be generated due to wrong XML configuration. If you would add more code related to this issue, I probably could isolate the exact reason behind this issue.

At my end, I wrote **di.xml** wrongly, I didn't write `<config>` tag in di.xml. For that reason, this error would generate.

I hope it helps!